# Scheduled Task issue - /usr/bin/php/: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, php, cron

Can't get it working, I want to set up a cron job for a domain user in plesk 11.5, but seems that there's a problem to find the php executable. The command is:

```
/usr/bin/php/ -f /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/httpdocs/test.php
```

but the report says

```
-: /usr/bin/php/: No such file or directory
```

Running CentOS 6.4 with Plesk 11.5

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

***find / -name php*** is giving me following:

```
/usr/include/php
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/php
/usr/lib64/php
/usr/share/php
/usr/share/psa-pear/pear/php
/usr/bin/php
/var/lib/php
```

while ***which php*** outputs this:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a trailing slash.
It should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/httpdocs/test.php
```

When getting an error like this, always try to verify with `ls` if you made mistake in the filename/path.

Comment: I've tried without that trailing slash, but same error message. However, perhaps this was one of some more problems with this task, so thanks for the hint.